# comstructing measurable set with below property

Tags: measure-theory

If $\delta >0$, $I_\delta=(-\delta,\delta)\in\mathbb{R}$, and $0\leq\alpha\leq\beta\leq1$, how to construct a measurable set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that as $\delta\to0$ we have the upper and lower limits of $\frac{m(E\cap I_\delta)}{2\delta}$ are $\beta$ and $\alpha$ (respectively)? (where m is the Lebesgue measure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to build such a set, is like this:

**Case $0<\alpha <\beta <1$**: Let $0<\gamma <x<1$. Let $E_0=(x,1] \cup [-1,-x)$, for all $i, E_i=\gamma^iE_0$ and $E=\cup_{i\geq 0} E_i$. We want $\gamma,x$ be s.t. they verify the following constraints:

i) For all $i$, $\frac{m(E\cap I_{\gamma^i})}{2\gamma^i} = \beta$.

ii) For all $i$, $\frac{m(E\cap I_{x\gamma^i})}{2x\gamma^i} = \alpha$.

(it's not hard to see this implies:
$$
\liminf_{\delta\to 0} \frac{m(E\cap I_{\delta})}{2\delta} = \alpha \\
\limsup_{\delta\to 0} \frac{m(E\cap I_{\delta})}{2\delta} = \beta \\
$$
which is what we are looking for)

Notice that $m(E\cap I_1)=m(E)=2\sum_{i\geq 0} m(\gamma^i(x,1])=2\sum_{i\geq 0} (1-x)\gamma^i = 2\left(\frac{1-x}{1-\gamma}\right)$, so $x,\gamma$ must verify 
$$
\frac{1-x}{1-\gamma}=\beta.
$$
On the other hand, we must have $\alpha = \frac{m(E\cap I_x)}{2x}=\frac{m(\cup_{i\geq 1}E_i)}{2x}=\frac{2\gamma \beta}{2x}$, hence 
$$
\gamma = x\frac{\alpha}{\beta}
$$
Hence, with a bit of algebra we deduce that $\gamma, x$ verify 
$$
(1-\beta)=x(1-\alpha)\\
\gamma = x\frac{\alpha}{\beta}
$$
With these values of $\gamma, x$, it is not difficult (but kind of tedious) to prove that the set $E$ does indeed verify i) and ii) and so it is a possible solution).

**Case $\alpha=0 < \beta < 1$**: We can use $E=\cup E_k$ with 
$$
E_k=((1-\beta)10^{-k^2}, 10^{-k^2}]\cup [-10^{-k^2}, (\beta-1)10^{-k^2}).
$$
We know $m(\cup_{j>k}E_j)=2\sum_{j>k}\beta\cdot 10^{-j^2}$, which implies
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{m(\cup_{j>k}E_j)}{2\cdot 10^{-k^2}} & = & \frac{\sum_{j>k}\beta\cdot 10^{-j^2}}{10^{-k^2}}\\
& = & \frac{\beta}{2}\sum_{j>k}\frac{10^{-j^2}}{10^{-k^2}}\\
& = & \frac{\beta}{2}\sum_{j>k}\frac{10^{-(k+(j-k))^2}}{10^{-k^2}}\\
& = & \frac{\beta}{2}\sum_{i>0}\frac{10^{-(k+i)^2}}{10^{-k^2}}\\
& = & \frac{\beta}{2}\sum_{i>0}\frac{10^{-k^2}}{10^{-k^2}}\cdot 10^{-2ki} \cdot 10^{-i^2}\\
& = & \frac{\beta}{2}\sum_{i>0} 10^{-2ki} \cdot 10^{-i^2}\\
& \leq & \frac{10^{-2k}\beta}{2}\sum_{i>0} 10^{-i^2}
\end{eqnarray} 
which goes to 0 as $k$ goes to $\infty$. Hence
$$
\frac{m(E\cap I_{10^{-k^2}})}{2\cdot 10^{-k^2}} = \frac{2\beta 10^{-k^2}}{2\cdot 10^{-k^2}} + \frac{m(\cup_{j>k}E_j)}{2\cdot 10^{-k^2}}\to \beta\\
\frac{m(E\cap I_{(1-\beta)10^{-k^2}})}{2\cdot (1-\beta)10^{-k^2}} = \frac{m(\cup_{j>k}E_j)}{2\cdot (1-\beta)10^{-k^2}}\to 0\\
$$
thus $E$ verifies the desired property.

**Case $0<\alpha < \beta = 1$**: Let the sequence $s_k=(s_{k-1})^2$ with $s_0=2$, and let $E=\cup E_k$ with 
$$
E_k=\left(\frac{10^{-s_{k+1}}}{\alpha}, 10^{-s_k}\right]\cup \left[-10^{-s_k}, -\frac{10^{-s_{k+1}}}{\alpha}\right).
$$

We can show (though it is likely to be pretty tedious) that $\frac{m(E\cap I_{10^{-s_{k}}})}{2\cdot 10^{-s_{k}}} \to 1$ as $k\to \infty$, and similarly, $\frac{m(E\cap I_{(10^{-s_{k+1}}/\alpha)})}{2\cdot (10^{-s_{k+1}}/\alpha)} \to \alpha$ as $k\to \infty$, thus $E$ verifies the desired property.

**Case $0=\alpha, \beta=1$**: Let the sequence $s_k=(s_{k-1})^4$ with $s_0=2$, and let $E=\cup E_k$ with 
$$
E_k=\left(10^{-s_k^2}, 10^{-s_k}\right]\cup \left[-10^{-s_k}, -10^{-s_k^2}\right).
$$

We can show that $\frac{m\left(E\cap I_{10^{-s_k}}\right)}{2\cdot 10^{-s_k}} \to 1$ as $k\to \infty$, and similarly, $\frac{m\left(E\cap I_{10^{-s_k^2}}\right)}{2\cdot 10^{-s_k^2}} \to 0$ as $k\to \infty$, thus $E$ verifies the desired property.

Comment: will this work when $\alpha $  and  $ \beta$ are same or when one is 0 and or other is 1...i think then your $\gamma$ and x will not satisfies your property.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I edited my answer taking into account all cases except $0\neq \alpha=\beta \neq 1$, as I'm kind of short of time right now.